# Limit latest news usinf foreach

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, foreach

How Can I set a limit for "Recent News" posts? I wanted to set a limit for 4, but it's showing all of them. As a bonus insert a "SEE ALL NEWS" button in the end...

I have this:

```
@foreach($news as $news)
    @php
        $news_img = ($news['anexo'] ? get_image_small_url($news['anexo']['ane_arquivo']) : '');
        $news_img = $news_img ?: 'http://placehold.it/300.jpg?text=%20';
        $news_txt = (empty($news['pub_resumo']) ? $news['pub_conteudo'] : $news['pub_resumo']);
    @endphp
    <div class="media media-thumb">
        @if($news_img)
            <div class="media-left">
                <a href="{{ url('/news/'.$news['post_id']) }}">
                    <img class="media-object" src="{{ $news_img }}" alt="{{ $news['pub_titulo'] }}">
                </a>
            </div>
        @endif
        <div class="media-body">
            <div class="post-meta">
                <span class="published">{{ date('d/m/Y', strtotime($news['pub_data_cadastro'])) }}</span>
                @if(!empty($news['categories']))
                    <span class="categories">{{ join(', ', array_column($news['categories'], 'tcp_nome')) }}</span>
                @endif
            </div>
            <h4 class="media-heading">
                <a href="{{ url('/news/'.$news['post_id']) }}">{{ $news['title'] }}</a>
            </h4>
            <p>{{ get_excerpt($news_txt, 180) }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

The controller

```
$news = Publicacao::select('publicacao_id', 'pub_titulo', 'pub_conteudo', 'pub_resumo', 'pub_data_cadastro', 'anexo_id')
        ->with(['categorias', 'anexo'])
        ->where('pub_tipo', 'NOT')
        ->where('pub_status', 'PUB')
        ->limit(5)
        ->orderBy('pub_data_cadastro', 'desc')
        ->get();

    $this->data['news'] = $news->toArray();

    return view('site.home', $this->data);
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: Maybe show your controller?

Comment: where ever you are getting `$news` from, why not ask it only for 4

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include just enough to reproduce the problem. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Good point lagbox. I'll try that and give a feedback soon.

Comment: I just send the controller Camilo. Check it out.
I know I can set limit for 4, but how about the Button SEE ALL NEWS?